# Is Cloudera Impala a Memory Consuming Framework?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata, impala

I am using bigdata in my project to crunch operation time that my ETL takes to execute.

I would like to understand is CloudEra Impala Framework memory intensive since it returns the results very fast and much more faster then hive and Pig.

I am having a data set of say 20-30 million records, and I perform a impala query operations like group by and joins

so Do you suggest to use impala as it is faster or use hive. My whole intention is to crunch my ETL operation time which is using Oracle right now..

Please advice with respect to memory usage and is it recommeded...

Also, if any links where we come to know how Impala works and how it uses its memory will be of great help.

Thanks.!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Impala is definitely memory intensive and much faster than Hive and Pig. For 30M records Hive will work faster than Oracle that you are using. If you have enough memory resources, hardware and if you have no other memory eating processes Impala is the best tool to use.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_cluster_sizing.html

This doumentation explains about memory requirements for Impala